# Error in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, android

i´m getting this error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions"

This is my Build Gradle for Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flappyfalcone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "3.1"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5]'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':adcolony')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my file in Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I want to use the files from Google Play Services to make ScoreBoard and Achievement but this happens my error´s .

Can you help me?

Comment: You probably forgot this `<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">` in your android manifest

Comment: When does this error arise? At execution time or at compile time? The complete stacktrace may help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what RustyX said, don't forget to complete the steps for enabling MultiDex. Your `build.gradle` is compiling the app with MultiDex support:

```
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
```

but you're also supporting Jellybean devices:

```
minSdkVersion 15
```

meaning that you have to do the steps in [the Multidex guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) in order to run on Jellybean and KitKat, namely use `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in the `<application>` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`, making your main app class extend from `MultiDexApplication` or call `MultiDex.install(Context)` when the app is being initialized.

Comment: I have that in my AndroidManifest.xml